# how to insert record to database with checkbox other option in php?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have form like this :

[image]

I am really confused how to put it all into a database. I have code like this :

```
echo "<form action='insert.php'>";
  $data = array("rice","fish","pizza","other");
  for($i=1; $i<5; $i++){
     echo "<input type='text' name='food[]' value='$i' class='food'><label>$data[$i]</label>";
  }
  echo "<input type='submit' value='ok'>";
echo "</form>";
<script>
    $(".food").change(function () {
        if (this.checked && this.value=='4') {
            $(this).next("label").after("<p id='other-text'><input placeholder='please enter food' type='text' name='otherfood[]' /></p>")
        } else {
            $("#other-text").remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

database:

```
order
id   id_food  other
----------------------
1       4      soup
```

Can you help me how to put it all into database tabel order like that ?

Comment: tried to implode() checkbox array?

Comment: There is no `INSERT` in the code provided. Where is that?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> order
> id   id_food  other
> ----------------------
> 1       4      soup
> ```

I don't think it's a good idea to store the data like that. If you really need to store `id_food = 4` (which refers to `'other'`) along with `'soup'`, I suggest customizing the food lookup table as follows:

```
food
id   name  is_other
----------------------
1    pizza 0
5    soup  1
```

And modifing the order table as follows

```
order
id   id_food  other_id
----------------------
1       4      5
```

This way you can preserve data integrity and keep the table size optimal by checking if the text provided in `other textbox` exists in `food` table and if it does select `id_food` and insert the `food_id` in `order` table.

And you can still filter checkboxes with the following condition if you do not wish manually entered `data` to visible on form

```
select id,name from food where is_other = 0
```

**Or**

Since you now have the data `soup` in `food` table, you can list it along with other food options as a `checkbox`.

This is one option, there are different approaches which I'm sure will be provided by other users.

Comment: i can't use your solution cz 'soup' can't be permanent, it can be 'noodle' or something else. So you can enter any name of food into the textbox belongs to the 'other '.

Comment: i see, you don't even have a `food` table.